# Dynamic CSS carousel changes size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a carousel using various sources.
I have a working demo now but i don't inderstand why changing the amount of items inside the carousel makes them change in size.

Can someone explain to me what is going on?
they appear to be more zoomed out.

http://codepen.io/sereal_killer/pen/zBPJAj

CSS:

```
.container-window {
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 170px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    top: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 210px;
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

#carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

#carousel .item{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 206px;
  height: 116px;
  left:0px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:grey;
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}

.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}


.next { right: 5em; }
.prev { left: 5em; }
```

JS

```
var carousel = document.getElementById("carousel")
var currdeg = 0;

var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("prev");
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("next");

var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var degreeToRotate = 360 / items.length

var tz = Math.round((items[0].offsetWidth / 2) /
  Math.tan(((Math.PI * 2) / items.length) / 2));

next[0].addEventListener("click", function () { rotate("n") });
prev[0].addEventListener("click", function () { rotate("p") });

//$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
//$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

setItemPos();

function setItemPos() {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.transform = "rotateY( " + (i*degreeToRotate) + "deg ) translateZ( " + tz + "px )";
    }
}


console.log(degreeToRotate);
function rotate(e) {
    if (e == "n") {
        currdeg = currdeg - degreeToRotate;
    }
    if (e == "p") {
        currdeg = currdeg + degreeToRotate;
    }

    carousel.style.transform = "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)";
    console.log("degree:" + currdeg);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it get's closer to the camera?

Comment: Yes i have figured as much now but i dont know how to adjust for it., a way to either move the rotation point further or the camera closer is what i am looking for but i gues i dont onderstand this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 4 items is perfect for this carousel, more will make some visual changes because of the rotations for each side.

Comment: But rotations and translate are dynamicly done, i dont understand why it seems to zoom out. with i remove items or zooms in when i add them

Comment: Yes I know, I think the rotate property is doing weird changes on item positionning ... And because it has more sides, the carousel object is wider and the front side is showing closer to us.

Comment: Hmm. I partly build it using this tutorial :https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/carousel.html But his example seems to be working fine. I am going thru the code again to figure out what i am doing different.